# Do you have any idea why my code does not work and I can not get the numbers while clicking

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I need help please If the next code.

I have two lines of

Now I want my code in JQ when the user clicks One of which

the Attribute of value will be printed to the screen.

Use the following code and I always undefined

Thank you very much for your help

```js
$(this).click(function (){
         var val = $('#223').attr("value");
       alert (val) ;
    })
```

```html
<html>
        <head>
            <title>Page Title</title>
            <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.1.1.js"></script>
        </head>
        <body>
        <p value="223">JQuery is </p>
        <p value="1.8">JQuery is </p>
    
        </body>
    </html>
```

Comment: Try using `data-value` instead of using value and combine with what below answers have mentioned. Also please do ready what data attributes are and why they are more frequently used.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `p` instead of `this`

```
$('p').click(function (){
     var val = $(this).attr("value");
   alert (val) ;
})
```

Example with your code:-

```js
$('p').click(function (){
     var val = $(this).attr("value");
   alert (val) ;
})
```

```html
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Page Title</title>
        <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.1.1.js"></script>
    </head>
    <body>
    <p value="223">JQuery is </p>
    <p value="1.8">JQuery is </p>

    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: @ShabiLevi  it worked . i have given you example with using your code only. check your browser console and see any error is there?

Comment: It works OK now I probably did not do stay I checked \\
Thanks digestion helped me very